# Inserting a directory in path for all directories in a folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt, subdirectory

I have this folder structure:

```
mainDir
----dira
--------(files/folders)
----dirb
--------(files/folders)
----dirc
--------(files/folders)
...
...
...
----dirz
--------(files/folders)
```

I want to loop through all directories under `mainDir`, create a folder named `xyz` in each dir under dirMain and move all contents from `dir#` (where # is a, b ... z) to `xyz` (under the respective dir).

The result would look like this:

```
mainDir
----dira
--------xyz
------------(files/folders)
----dirb
--------xyz
------------(files/folders)
----dirc
--------xyz
------------(files/folders)
...
...
...
----dirz
--------xyz
------------(files/folders)
```

is this possible using a batch file as i have too many folders to do this manually.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried on your own? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So far I've tried searching for how to do it without having to write a separate set of command for each folder and repeat for other folders. Stuck at could not find anything. Have never written something like this before. So dont have code to share if that's what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply work out the steps you need to do on each folder. You can use wildcards to bulk MOVE or RENAME a set of files. But folders must be MOVEd or RENAMEd individually.

- Create xyz folder
- Move all files to xyz folder
- Move each subfolder (except xyz) to xyz folder

Then execute those steps for each folder using a FOR /D loop.

```
@echo off
for /d %%F in (main\*) do (
  pushd "%%F"
  md "xyz"
  move * "xyz" >nul
  for /d %%G in (*) do if "%%G" neq "xyz" move "%%G" "xyz" >nul
  popd
)
```